# Problems with CSS selectivity

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble with some CSS code. I'm trying to have a certain class of links be red while the rest are blue. Here is my code:

```
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color : blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a.headerLink
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: "#983030";
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

The a.headerLink should have more selectivity to it so the color property would override it, but it's not. And what's more is that it's only happening to the color. The padding and font weight properties are correct, but for some reason the color isn't overriding. Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Remove the double quotes `"` around the hex color.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

CSS colours must not be quoted.

```
color: "#983030";
```

should be

```
color: #983030;
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the validator

Answer (score 0):

Use a valid form of color for this color property. You can do this by using Hexadecimal colors, HSLA ,HSL , RGB & RGBA. Some examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp).

> a {
>       text-decoration: none;
>       color : blue;
>       cursor: pointer; }
>
> a.headerLink {
>       text-decoration: none;
>       **color: #983030;**
>       font-weight: bold;
>       padding-right: 20px; }

Answer (score -1):

Oh i see it. You should take off the quotes around your color-hex! It should look like this:

```
a.headerLink {
text-decoration: none;
color: **#983030**;
font-weight: bold;
padding-right: 20px;
```

}
You should ony use quotes for things such as URLs and when you are adding classes and IDs to an html selector.
Hope it helped!